# How to make elements inside div same height and width even when contents are different?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create "cards" for my team. However, the look weird because the dimensions are different. 
My set up looks like this:

```
<div class="card-wrapper">
<div class="card">Card1</div>
<div class="card">Card2</div>
</div>
```

My css looks like this now:

```
.card-wrapper
{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
flex-direction: row;
}
.card
{
width: 30rem;
background: #000;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to make the height the same for all cards. I saw here on stackoverflow that I should:

```
.card-wrapper {
display:flex;
}
.card {
flex:1;
}
```

But that does not seem to work. Any suggestions?
Here is a picture of what it currently looks like:
[CARDS NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OQX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think is because you use

> align-items: center

just remove it should have same height for these two card

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sevm5b

Answer (score 0):

Setting a flex-basis would be helpful. Moreover you don't need the align-items and align-content for this.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:20vh
}


.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  flex: 0 1 33.33%;
  padding: 15px; /* gutter width */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"><br></div>
  <div class="card"><br></div>
  <div class="card"><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```